# Turning String Into Array

Tags: php

I have the following string which I've managed to get cleaned up into a clear format:

```
string(191) "twitter:3 facebookshare_count:5 like_count:0 comment_count:0 total_count:8 click_count:5 buffer:0 pinterest:0 linkedin:0 stumbleupon:0 redditscore:0 ups:8 downs:3 google:4 delicious:0 digg:0 "
```

I am now trying to take this and create an array so each digit is associated with its platform.

```
$shares = array(
'twitter' => 3,
'facebookshare_count' => 5,
'like_count' => 0
)
```

and so on...

I've been looking at the explode function, using spaces as the delimiter, but I'm really stuck on how to achieve this end result.

I am relatively new to PHP, and struggling to find the words to use to search for this problem. I don't know if 'array' or 'object' is even the right terminology here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'twitter:3 facebookshare_count:5 like_count:0 comment_count:0 total_count:8 click_count:5 buffer:0 pinterest:0 linkedin:0 stumbleupon:0 redditscore:0 ups:8 downs:3 google:4 delicious:0 digg:0';

$strArray = explode(' ', $str);
$desiredArray = [];
foreach ($strArray as $value) {
    $value = explode(":", $value);
    $desiredArray[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myString = "twitter:3 facebookshare_count:5 like_count:0 comment_count:0 total_count:8 click_count:5 buffer:0 pinterest:0 linkedin:0 stumbleupon:0 redditscore:0 ups:8 downs:3 google:4 delicious:0 digg:0";

$parseString = explode(" ", $myString);
$newArray = [];

foreach($parseString as $item) {
    $splitItem = explode(":", $item);
    $newArray[$splitItem[0]] = $splitItem[1];
}

foreach($newArray as $key=>$data) {
    echo $key . " " . $data . "<br>";
}
```

Hope it helps !!!